# SharePoint 2013 Service Application Error

Tags: .net, iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am unable to get multiple SharePoint service applications working. When I navigate to any service url e.g: http...MetadataWebService.svc I receive the error "Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify that you are running in a 64-bit executable." I have changed the SharePoint Web Services Root Enable 32-bit Applications to false in IIS Application Pools but the error remains.

Here's the rest of the error

> [PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify that you are running in a 64-bit executable.]
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CheckFrameworkAndProcess() +281
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_RegistryConnectionString() +37
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Local() +83
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined) +171
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_Local() +49
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceApplication.get_Current() +216
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceHostOperations.Configure(ServiceHostBase serviceHost, SPServiceAuthenticationMode authenticationMode) +26
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceApplication.ConfigureServiceHost(ServiceHostBase serviceHost, SPServiceAuthenticationMode authenticationMode) +13
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +47
>      System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1434
>      System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52
>      System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service '/3dbfec4a10a642c296f8fd5bd2d521bd/MetadataWebService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify that you are running in a 64-bit executable..]
>      System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +499812
>      System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178
>      System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult ar) +350382
>      System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +9549077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other application pools used by sharepoint service applications outside of the "sharepoint web services root" one. Look at all the application pools in use (particularly the ones with long strings of numbers and letters as names) and ensure they also have enable 32-bit set to `false`.

Comment: That fixed everything.